# What is zero-shot vs one-short vs few-shot learning?

Tags: finetuning, one-shot-learning, few-shot-learning, zero-shot-learning

## Are there any papers/research work that deals with generalizing the matrix of how the `*-shot(s) learning` are defined?

There's a wide variety of papers that titled themselves as `*-shot(s) learning`, with some variants of how `*-shot`s are defined, e.g.

- **Classic ML learning** [i.e. **No free lunch**] Model is trained on `task A` on training split of `dataset B` and evaluated using the same `task A` on held-out or cross-validated splits of `dataset B`
- **Zero-shot learning** in the context pre-trained / foundation model

  - **Variant 1:** [i.e. ***Train task A on data B, eval task A on data C***] The model is trained on `task A` but on `dataset B` but the model seems to work for `task A + eval on dataset C` by capitalizing on representation learnt from `task A + train on dataset B` where dataset C and B shares some commonality but also different enough to call the usage of the model on dataset C "zero-shot"

    - i.e. Same task, different data domain/features
    - e.g. Model trained for Machine translation (`task A`) task on English-Spanish + French-Spanish (`dataset B`) and evaluated on French-Spanish data (`dataset C`)
  - **Variant 2:** [i.e. ***Train on task X on data B, eval task Y with data B/C***] The model is trained on `task X` and `dataset B` and evaluated on `task Y` on `dataset C` that has same properties as `dataset B` but may/may not different as much as how datasets differs in Variant 1.

    - i.e. Different task, same/different data domain/features
    - e.g. Model trained for language modelling (`task X`) with a classifier head on Wikipedia text (`data B`) and evaluated on text classification (`task Y`) on either Wiki text (`data B`) or user-generated Twitter text (`data C`)
- **One-shot learning** in context of general gradient-based or optimization/prediction based ML

  - **Variant 1:** Trained `task A` on **a single epoch/pass** through the `dataset B` and evaluated on held-out / cross-validated splits of `dataset B`
  - **Variant 2:** Trained `task A` on **a single data point** from `dataset B` and evaluated on held-out / cross-validated splits of `dataset B`
  - **Variant 3:** Trained `task A` on **a single epoch/pass** / **a single data point**  from `dataset B` and evaluated in a "zero-shot" manner with `task X` on `dataset B` or `dataset C`

    - Is this then "zero-one-shot learning"? Is there a name for this? "One-shot learning/training, zero-shot evaluation"?
  - **Variant 4:** Model is pre-trained for `task A` till convergence from `dataset B` and  **fine-tuned on a single epoch/pass / a single data point**  for either

    - `task A` with `dataset C` (one-shot domain adaptation)
    - `task X` with `dataset B` (one-shot task adaptation)
    - `task X` with `dataset C` (one-shot domain + task adaptation)

And for **Few-shot learning**, the premise seems to the same as one-shot but instead of **a single epoch/data point**, it's **a few epoch/data points**

To kind of put the above into tables:

| Shots | (pre-)Train for | (pre-)Train on | (pre-)Train no. data | Tune for | Tune on | Tune no. data | Eval for | Eval on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Classic | task A | data B (train) | data B till converge | task A | data B (valid) | all data B (valid) | task A | data B (test) |
| Zero | task A | data B (train) | data B till converge | - | - | - | task A | data C |
| Zero | task A | data B (train) | data B till converge | - | - | - | task X | data B / C |

| Shots | (pre-)Train for | (pre-)Train on | (pre-)Train no. data | Tune for | Tune on | Tune no. data | Eval for | Eval on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | task A | data B (train) | data B one epoch | - | - | - | task A | data B (test) |
| One | task A | data B (train) | data B one data point | - | - | - | task A | data B (test) |
| One | task A | data B (train) | data B one epoch / one data point | - | - | - | task X | data B / C |
| One | task A | data B (train) | all data B (train) | task X | data B / C | one epoch / one data point | task X | data B / C |

| Shots | (pre-)Train for | (pre-)Train on | (pre-)Train no. data | Tune for | Tune on | Tune no. data | Eval for | Eval on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Few | task A | data B (train) | data B a few epoch | - | - | - | task A | data B (test) |
| Few | task A | data B (train) | data B a few data point | - | - | - | task A | data B (test) |
| Few | task A | data B (train) | data B a few epoch / a few data point | - | - | - | task X | data B / C |
| Few | task A | data B (train) | all data B (train) | task X | data B / C | a few epoch / a few data point | task X | data B / C |

The matrix of what counts as zero-shot, one-shot, few-shot is kinda fuzzy.

### Are there other variants of the `*-shot(s) learning` that the above matrix didn't manage to cover?

Comment: Thanks for that question. I also struggle to get an unique definition and I feel like some paper use a loose definition on purpose to get a better title. One thing that might be of importance and that is not covered in your question is the size of the dataset. Single pass on a Small / Medium / Big / Gigantic dataset is not the same thing.